# How to find String.indexOf("\")?

Tags: java, string

I need to get the substring that appears before a bunch of \r\n\r\n junk.  So I want to geto the first /that appears.  indexOf("\") is not accepted.  String.indexOf("\") does not match the first .  ?????
Thanks

Comment: Sorry \r\n\r\n       is the string

Comment: `String s = "hello\r\n";s =s.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for the first occurrence of `\n` in a string then searching for `\\` won't help.  You need to look for `\n`.

```
String.indexOf("\n")
```

Note that `\n` is one character, not two.  It's an escape sequence that evaluates to the character with ASCII value 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s1 = "LINE1\r\n\r\nLINE2";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".+").matcher(s1);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
} else {
    System.out.println("String contains no character other than \\n and \\r");
}
```

or a bit more perverted:

```
String s1 = "LINE1\r\n\r\nLINE2";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(s1));
try {
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Output in both cases: `LINE1`

Answer (score 0):

```
indexOf("/")
```

should work fine. Why do you say it is not?

Comment: Sorry \r\n\r\n is the string  and \\ does not find it

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
System.out.println( "abc//def//".indexOf("/") );
```

Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why does `indexOf('/')` not work? Does it return the wrong index? Forward slashes should be fine -- backward slashes (`\`) are escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

if '\' is what you are trying to find, use .indexOf("\");

Comment: wtf, I wrote \\ with two \s, not one